# emberjs has_many association gives unloaded data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am new to the ember js, I have a json response to the ember model

```
   {:login_fields=>
        [
        {:component=>"ns4:FieldInfoComponent",
         :id=>1,
         :fieldinfos=>
           [{:fieldInfoObj=>"FieldInfoSingle", :id=>2, :login_field_id=>1}],
         :fieldinfo_ids=>[2]},
        {:component=>"ns4:FieldInfoComponent",
         :id=>2,
         :fieldinfos=>
           [{:fieldInfoObj=>"FieldInfoSingle", :id=>2, :login_field_id=>2}],
         :fieldinfo_ids=>[2]}
      ]
    }
```

And loginField model of emberjs:

```
App.LoginField = DS.Model.extend
  component: DS.attr 'string'
  fieldinfos: DS.hasMany('App.Fieldinfo')
```

FieldInfo model:

```
App.Fieldinfo = DS.Model.extend
  login_field: DS.belongsTo 'App.LoginField'
  fieldInfoObj: DS.attr 'string'
```

The ember response that I get contains fields and correct values of the loginfield model and also associates it with the fieldinfo model but the data of the fieldinfo shows like **Object { id="2", clientId=5, data="loading", more...}**
Why don't I get the actual data for the has_many model?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ember docs about model relationships](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships):

The JSON should encode the relationship as an array of IDs:

```
{
  "post": {
    "comments": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

Then [sideloaded](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships) if you want to get all in info in a single request:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Node is not omakase",
    "comments": [1, 2, 3]
  },

  "comments": [{
    "id": 1,
    "body": "But is it _lightweight_ omakase?"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "body": "I for one welcome our new omakase overlords"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "body": "Put me on the fast track to a delicious dinner"
  }]
}
```

The problem with your json is that Ember expects `field_infos` to be an array of ids, and for you it's the actual objects. Then, to compound the issue, `field_infos` is an array of fieldInfoObjs. Whee, what fun!

If you have any control over the json, I'd recommend changing it to be more in line with [what EmberData expects](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/models/the-rest-adapter/).

If you don't have any control over the incoming JSON, comment on this answer and I can try to guide you to the resource you'll need.

Comment: Kori thanks for the reply, actually here what I try to do is loading multiple login_fields where each login field has_many fieldinfos